# Book about a space war with lizards and mind-controlling space turtles

Tags: story-identification, novel, space

Looking for the title of a book, pre-1980.

Its basic plot is a space war with the ending being the discovery of a species of small turtles that controlled the minds of the warring alien race, which I believe was lizards. They were carried around in the weapons of the lizards. The alien helping the main character boiled the turtle in the water it was kept in using its mind.

Comment: Who else was involved in the war, besides the lizards and the turtles? And who or what was the main character?

Answer (score 20):

This is Harry Harrison's 1973 novel *[Star Smashers of the Galaxy Rangers](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1127)*

> Now their eyes were drawn across the room and down. Down towards the
> table. Down towards the bowl of water. Down to the little green turtle
> that was waving its tiny claws at them.
>
> "Pishky...*you*!" Troceps gasped.
>
> "Lord Pishky, if you don't mind..."

........

> "The first rat leaves the sinking spaceship," Lord Pishky sneered, which is very hard to do if you are a turtle.

.........

> They watched in frozen silence as the tiny, yet extremely evil
> creature paddled about furiously as the water began to bubble.