Short novel where kids travel through tiny parallel universe
I read in the late 1970s/early 1980s a rather tongue-in-cheek book about two boys, maybe brothers, roughly high school or college age, where they invent an FTL drive.  The principal of operation is that the drive momentarily transfers their ship into a nearby alternate universe that's only about a mile and a half in diameter, so that any small shift in their position there translates into a proportional distance in our universe.
IIRC, one of their first adventures is swooping down on a field where hideous aliens are chasing a crowd of humanoids, so they intervene on behalf of the humanoids, decimating the aliens.  They subsequently find out that the hideous aliens are sentient, while the humanoids are a form of cattle.
I don't think it's by a well-known author, at least under their well-known name.  I had misremembered the cattle rescue scene as coming from Kilgore Trout's "Venus on the Half Shell," but remembered this story when I found I was wrong.  It's a similar mockery-of-bad-sf vibe, but less explicit, probably for a YA audience.

If the space drive works as said, assume the real universe is one billion light years in diameter and there are 6 trillion miles in a light year.  if the other universe is 1.5 miles in diameter, the ratio of distances is about 4 quintillion times.  If they wanted to travel 1 light year in our universe they would have to travel a very minute fraction of an inch in our universe.  I find it rather hard to believe that their controls could be precise enough to reach the same planet twice.

IIRC, that was mentioned in the book but glossed over; it might have been treated as an excuse they couldn't operate it with great accuracy.  It wasn't meant to be a hard SF classic.  And I'd estimate more like 14Bly for the radius of the universe, even ignoring expansion artifacts.

Sounds like probably Star Smashers of the Galaxy Rangers a 1973 novel by Harry Harrison

I read in the late 1970s/early 1980s

Checck 1973.

a rather tongue-in-cheek book about two boys, maybe brothers, roughly high school or college age,

Check. Two college students, Chuck van Chider and his friend Jerry Courtenay,

where they invent an FTL drive. The principal of operation is that the drive momentarily transfers their ship into a nearby alternate universe that's only about a mile and a half in diameter, so that any small shift in their position there translates into a proportional distance in our universe.

Check. "accidentally invent a device that can transport them through space, powered by a substance called "Cheddite", which is created by irradiating cheddar cheese."

IIRC, one of their first adventures is swooping down on a field where hideous aliens are chasing a crowd of humanoids, so they intervene on behalf of the humanoids, decimating the aliens. They subsequently find out that the hideous aliens are sentient, while the humanoids are a form of cattle.

Check. In fact, as part of the propoganda from the humanoids they are showing 'butchering' education tapes to show the aliens as being vicious. Spoiler alert:

  We find out the humanoids (as well as other races) are being controlled by miniature turtle aliens which is why they appear sentient. Whent the turtle is removed the humanoid drops down and starts cropping vegetation like any other farm/meat animal.


I don't think it's by a well-known author, at least under their well-known name.

Miss. Harry Harrison wrote this under his regular name.

It's a similar mockery-of-bad-sf vibe, but less explicit, probably for a YA audience.

Check.  The main characters are homages to Tom Swift Jr. and his buddy, Bud Barclay. It also includes a homage to Larry Niven for a Ringworld.

Also the unaccepted answer here https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/283364/28516 "LORD Pishky, if you don't mind..."
